# Поиск нужного значения в ассоциативном массиве объектов из файла JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Есть API с данными о серверах в виде JSON файла servers.json. Мне нужно выводить информацию об онлайне **только первого сервера** на сайт. Индексы в JSON файле могут меняться, поэтому `console.log(servers[0])` не подходит. Может как-то устроить проверку значений IP и port и если совпадает с первым сервером, то получать его онлайн.

Мой код:

```
const requestURL = 'URL для получения JSON файла';

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

xhr.open('GET', requestURL)

xhr.responseType = 'json'

xhr.onload = () => {
    servers = xhr.response
    console.log(servers)
}

xhr.send()
```

Файл имеет следующий вид:

```
[
    {
        "ip": "194.61.3.51",
        "port": 25590,
        "online": 20
    },
    {
        "ip": "194.61.3.51",
        "port": 25520,
        "online": 15
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Устанавливаем ip и порт, которые хотим найти и с помощью метода find возвращаем первый элемент, проходящий проверку:

```
const firstServerIp = "194.61.3.51"
const firstServerPort = 25590

const result = servers.find((server) => server.ip === firstServerIp && server.port === firstServerPort)

return result
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: И как это вставить в код чтобы вывести в консоль?

Comment: @ces-are выводите резалт.

Comment: @MrYogurt когда вывожу резалт в консоль лог, то выдает ошибку, можете показать как это получилось у вас?

Comment: @ces-are а что у меня могло получиться? Я же не могу воспроизвести ваш код. Как и не могу догадаться, что у вас за ошибка, цените мое и свое время.

Comment: @ces-are кстати да, прошу прощения, проглядел, что у вас порт это намбер, а не стринг, поменяйте переменную firstServerPort = "25590" на firstServerPort = 25590